# Unity 2D loading Spritesheet Atlas at runtime from web and using it dynamically

Tags: 2d, unity, sprites, spritesheet, texture-atlas

I am new to Unity (came from AS3/Starling) and just started for 2D games in Unity. I have a spritesheet / texture-atlas (many different sized images packed in a single png) which I want to download at runtime (I can use WWW classes for that) in game .

Than use all those images (in that sprite atlas) and show them up on screen and use them as regular unity sprites, like applying Rigidbody2D or Collider2D etc. I googled for this but mainly what I found is using Unity3D's editor, importing the sprite atlas and using its own sprite editor. Not much on how I would do that in runtime. I am expecting something like what we used to do in Flash or evening in Cocos2d, like we have a related XML file for each sprite atlas and their SDK have functions for reading that sprite in conjunction with that XML.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html). I think it sums it up. Did not take long to google.

Comment: Ya, I already read this. But this only gives how to load resources at runtime but not how to specifically manage multiple sized sprite atlases loaded at runtime.

Comment: I am not familiar with it (hence no answer) but wouldn't you need to prepare the asset in advance, put it online and the load it during runtime? I think the management part happens offline before you upload the assets. I think unity is expecting you to do things a certain way where AS3 is more of a set of tools where you do what you want ( I could be wrong).

Comment: Ya, normally we don't need to do these kind of things but the requirement for my game is like that only. I want to download different set of images at runtime and based on that images the game play happens. Its like there will be 100-150 images that will be downloaded. So I thought why not to group them in a atlas (also they are of different size) but even after making atlas and downloading it, how will I get to know which image is fo what size and x/y positions, except I store that information in a xml/txt file (and how will I read that file in Unity?)?.